# XAMPP Apache mod_jk.so not working

Tags: apache, xampp, httpd.conf

I'm experiencing problems adding `mod_jk.so` to my modules folder on my XAMPP installation file. 
After copying the file to the modules file, I ran the following command:

```
C:\xamp\apache\bin>httpd.exe -t
```

Each time I do this I get the following response -

> Syntax error on line 22 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/mod-jk.conf: Cannot
>   load modules/mod_jk.so into server: The specified procedure could not
>   be found.

- even when my `mod_fk.so` file is in the right location

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it also gave me the same error and when I changed to apache 64bit instead of 32bit, it worked without errors.

I hope this help.

Comment: This answer could be improved by a bit deeper/clearer explanation of what the underlying problem was. Are you suggesting the cause of the error is a mismatch in the type of the module and the type of the applications? or a mismatch in the application with the OS/machine it was running on?